# Suppressing logging in spring batch with spring boot

Tags: spring, logging

I am following the Spring batch with Spring boot tutorial here:

```
https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/
```

I have the following in POM

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And the parent as:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

I am getting `DEBUG` logs in my console automatically.

How do I suppress it? No matter what I put in my `application.properties`, its not going away.

Its really frustrating.

Lines I tried in `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.batch: ERROR  
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR
```

and

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web: ERROR  
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR
```

Tried by replacing : with = -- got same result

This also doesn't work.

```
logging.level.=ERROR
```

Comment: Are you using `log4j` or `slf4j`?

Comment: @chsdk: Using nothing. I followed what's there in the tutorial. Seems its something which came with Spring Boot.

Comment: So it uses `logback` by defualt, is there a `logback.xml` file in your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a logback.xml with the following lines resolved the issue:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.batch" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc" level="ERROR"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's what I was about to suggest :), as it's what they use in the [**Spring logging documentation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html).